# Dockerfile vs docker run

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I am having a problem with published ports in Docker using Dockerfile compared to using docker run manually. Using the following command, the Docker container starts successfully, and when I visit the Host IP address (192.168.99.100) in the browser with http://192.168.99.100:8080 – the RabbitMQ Web Management Dashboard loads.

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3.5.6-management
```

At this point, I run the following to free up the ports I want to use from the Dockerfile:

```
docker stop some-rabbit
```

When I run the following docker-compose commands, once I visit the same URL above (http://192.168.99.100:8080) I receive "This site can’t be reached 192.168.99.100 refused to connect."

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Here is the Dockerfile I am using:

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbitmq:
        container_name: rabbit
        hostname: rabbit
        ports:
            - "8080:15762"
        image: rabbitmq:3.5.6-management
```

Below is the result of `docker ps` after `docker run`

```
6c5a97bd51bc rabbitmq:3.5.6-management "/docker-entrypoint.s" 16 seconds ago Up 15 seconds 4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->15672/tcp some-rabbit
```

Below is the result of `docker ps` after `docker-compose up -d`

```
99987aeb5cbf rabbitmq:3.5.6-management "/docker-entrypoint.s" 13 seconds ago Up 11 seconds 4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15671-15672/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->15762/tcp rabbitmq
```

Comment: maybe you should rm container after you stop it. try docker rm some-rabbit after docker stop. then try docker-compose up -d.

Comment: Why are you doing `docker-compose build`? Also what's the result of `docker-compose ps` after the `docker-compose up -d`.

Comment: @kyur, I have also used docker rm some-rabbit after docker stop to no avail.

Comment: @JHarris I've added the results of `docker ps` to the bottom of my question

Answer (score 3):

After further testing, I discovered that all ports used by RabbitMQ must be explicitly published in the Dockerfile.

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbitmq:
        container_name: rabbitmq
        hostname: rabbitmq
        ports:
            - "4369:4369"
            - "5672:5672"
            - "15672:15672"
            - "25672:25672"
        image: rabbitmq:3.5.5-management
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering your own question

Comment: This looks like a `docker-compose.yml` and not a `Dockerfile`